# DRYing up JavaScript functions taking optional arguments and a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js it is, for several reasons, customary/recomended to pass a callback to a function as the last argument.  There may also be one or more optional arguments, which we would like to pass *before* the callback.  You end up with seeing a lot of very repetitive code, such as

```
// receiveMessages([options], [callback])
function receiveMessages(options, callback) {
   if(typeof options === 'function'){
      callback = options;
      options = {}; // or some other sensible default
   }
   //...
 }
```

Adding additional optional arguments means adding an additional check, of course:

```
 // through([dest], [options], [callback])
 function through(dest, options, callback) {
     if(typeof dest === 'function'){
        callback = dest;
        dest = noop();
        options = {};
     }else if(typeof options === 'function'){
        callback = options;
        options = {};
     }
     // ...
 }
```

**Edit** This pattern [appears](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/dns.js#L177-L192) [all](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L391-L401) [over](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L169-L180) the standard library as well.

I can think of a few hacky ways of DRYing this up, but I'm wondering if anyone has an especially elegant or generic solution to get the arguments bound to the correct positional parameters.

Comment: If performance isn't an issue, write a function that does this.

Comment: @mzedeler: It's not the performance that's the issue, it's the fact that writing it like this is ugly as hell, and more importantly, unmaintainable as hell.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Exactly.

Comment: As I said - if performance *isn't* an issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that comes to my mind is method overloading. Technically this is not supported in JavaScript but there are some way to realize something like this. John Resig has an article about it in his blog: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/

In addition, here is my implementation, that is very similar to John Resig's and highly inspiried by it:

```
var createFunction = (function(){
    var store = {};

    return function(that, name, func) {
        var scope, funcs, match;

        scope = store[that] || (store[that] = {});
        funcs = scope[name] || (scope[name] = {});

        funcs[func.length] = func;

        that[name] = function(){
            match = funcs[arguments.length];
            if (match !== undefined) {
                return match.apply(that, arguments);
            } else {
                throw "no function with " + arguments.length + " arguments defined";
            }
        };
    };
}());
```

This enables you to define the same function several times with a different number of arguments each time:

```
createFunction(window, "doSomething", function (arg1, arg2, callback) {
    console.log(arg1 + " / " + arg2 + " / " + callback);
});

createFunction(window, "doSomething", function (arg1, callback) {
    doSomething(arg1, null, callback);
});
```

This piece of code defines a global function `doSomething`, one time with three and one time with two arguments. As you see, the first downside of this method is that you have to provide an object to which the functions are being attached, you cannot just say "define a function right here". Also, the function declarations are a little bit more complicated then before. But you can now call your function with a different number of arguments and getting the right result without the use of repeating `if..else` structures:

```
doSomething("he", function(){});         //he / null / function(){}
doSomething("he", "ho", function(){});   //he / ho / function(){}
```

So far, only the number of arguments matter but I can think of extending this, to also react on different data types, so that one can also differentiate between the following:

```
function doSomething(opt1, opt2, callback){
    //some code
}

doSomething({anObject: "as opt1"}, function(){});
doSomething("a string as opt2", function(){});
```

Nevertheless, this is probably not the best way to go but it can be convinient in certain circumstances. For a lot of optional arguments, I personally like Pumbaa80's answer of putting those options in one required object-argument.

Answer (score 2):

> In Node.js it is, for several reasons, customary/recomended to pass a callback to a function as the last argument

The only reason I can think of is forcing the developers to provide the other arguments.

For example, `function (success, error)` would result in sloppy programming, since lazy coders would simply omit the `error` callback. That's why you commonly see `function (error, success)`.

That being said, the convention above is great for *mandatory* arguments. If you want *optional* arguments, just don't do that. One way to handle this scenario is the following scheme:

```
function (required1, required2, ..., callback, options)
// or
function (required1, required2, ..., options, callback)
```

where each optional argument may or may not be provided as an attribute of `options`.

**Edit**: actually, this is used in some node libraries, e.g. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: The reason for doing so is to provide flexible function signatures in a language without compile time polymorphism.
  
It's everywhere in the standard library (see edit), so I think it can generally be regarded as solid practice.

Comment: @jjm That's tautological. You're saying the reason for providing flexible function signatures is to provide flexible function signatures. I highly doubt there's any benefits in this. Just because the standard lib does it wrong, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: So the signature of `request.end` should be `end(chunk, encoding, callback)`, not `end([chunk], [encoding], [callback])`?  By giving you the option to omit arguments, the function doesn't make you guess how you should tell it to end the request with no additional data, what a good encoding to use for http requests is, and whether you have to provide a callback function every time.

`function(required1,required2,...,callback, optional)` will confuse not only other developers but libraries like async.js and underscore, which expect this convention in function signatures.

Comment: No, the signature should be `writable.end(options)`, and called with named parameters like so `writable.end({callback:foo})`. Indeed, node does use this kind of pattern too, for example [in `fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options), but not everywhere, which is a bit confusing.